# Spring MongoDB- ConditionalOperators

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin

I have to transform such MongoDB query to Spring (Kotlin) code:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "emptyField": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$name",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              ""
            ]
          },
          "then": 0,
          "else": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In Kotlin I have:

```
val ifNullCondition = ConditionalOperators.ifNull("name").then("")

val criteria = Criteria.where(
     ifNullCondition //how to deal with it
).`is`("")

val outerCondition = ConditionalOperators.Cond.`when`(criteria).then(0).otherwise(1)
```

How to add `ConditionalOperators.ifNull`to the criteria to process it?

When I try something like this:

```
val criteria = Criteria.where(
                ifNullCondition.toDocument().toJson()
            ).`is`("")
```

I get some extra characters something like:
`["${\"$ifNull\" : [\"$name\", \"\"]}", ""`